# Hibernate: insert data into DB

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have this code but I don't know where is the query that inserts data into DB:

```
public boolean regNotification(Notifiche notifiche){

     Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();
     if(isNotificationExists(notifiche)) return false;
     Transaction tx = null; 
     try {
         tx = session.getTransaction();
         tx.begin();
         session.saveOrUpdate(notifiche);
         tx.commit();
     } catch (Exception e) {
         if (tx != null) {
             tx.rollback();
         }
         e.printStackTrace();
     } finally {
         session.close();
         //System.out.println("Closing Session");
     }  
     return true;
}
```

Comment: TO insert data into db with hibernate, you need to open and close transaction. So full code is : `tx = session.getTransaction();
         tx.begin();
         session.saveOrUpdate(notifiche);
         tx.commit();`

Comment: Method `saveOrUpdate` tell hibernate wether to save or update atabase on transaction commit

Comment: yes, i think I wrote that.

Comment: but when it does the query " insert into table(column1, column2 ,column3) values (?, ?, ?)"?

Comment: This query is executed on transaction commit. You can check if this is true by enabling hibernate logging and set breakpoint on commit

Comment: @Daniele read up on Hibernate and why it exists, looks like you're missing some basics.

Comment: thanks all, already solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This inserts the data:

```
session.saveOrUpdate(notifiche);
```

This commits your changes:

```
tx.commit();
```

You can also use HQL, but the idea of Hibernate is using objects like sessions and transactions to abstract you from SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your code working properly
Create session should be: Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
other lines of code i think is ok.
session.saveOrUpdate(notifiche); --> Will insert(if not exist in db) or update (if exist in db) data to db.
Hope this help.